# MySQL - Select last record from second table matching with first table

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-tables

I have two tables customers and orders, below is the structure.

**Table - customers**

- id
- customer_name

**Table - orders**

- id
- order_id
- customer_id

customers table have customers records and orders table have orders placed by customers,

**customer_id** in orders table is linked to the **id** field of customers table.

Now one customer can have zero or one or more than one orders, i want to get the last order placed by customers only.

when i run the following query a simple invisible join, it returns all the orders by the customer

```
SELECT customers.customer_name,orders.order_id FROM orders,customers WHERE orders.customer_id=customers.id
```

I have also tried different JOIN statements but cannot get the last order by the customer, i want to get it in one SQL query for all customers.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   c.customer_name, 
   max(o.order_id)
FROM 
   customers c
INNER JOIN
   orders o
ON
   o.customer_id = c.id
GROUP BY 
   c.customer_name
```

You don't have any date field in the order table so assuming the latest order will be the one which has `max(order_id)`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, if order_id is random then this wouldn't work, but this is the nearest to the what i am looking for.

Comment: I have solved it with the following; `SELECT c.customer_name, o.customer_id, o.order_id,o.id
FROM customers c
  INNER JOIN orders o ON o.id =
    (SELECT id FROM orders
       WHERE customer_id = c.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) `

Comment: Yes it would won't work if order_id is random, then you should have date field from which we can get a order_date and find the latest order

Comment: @Alyas Very nice solution. Thank you.

Comment: this works, but what if I have a datetime field ,and I want to use that fields?@Meherzad

Comment: hello everyone. i am more than happy to write this comment as today in 2022 and this query from @Ayas has saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

In MySQL there is just few ways to make it work (*that I now actually*). The first one is sort your table as `desc` before the `join`:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, o.customer_id, o.order_id,o.id FROM customers c 
INNER JOIN orders o 
    ON o.id = (SELECT id FROM orders WHERE customer_id = c.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Using in real time is the only way to get it done, but if you need to make some join on not real time you can create a temporary table or a alias table sorting it to make your select, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_your_table AS 
SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id DESC
```

So now you are able to make this join work:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, o.customer_id, o.order_id,o.id FROM customers c 
INNER JOIN tmp_your_table o ON o.id = tmp_your_table.id
```

Comment: This part helped me for my query `INNER JOIN orders o 
    ON o.id = (SELECT id FROM orders WHERE customer_id = c.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   c.customer_name, 
   o.order_id
FROM 
   customers c
INNER JOIN
   orders o
ON
   o.customer_id = c.id
ORDER BY 
   o.id desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This would only return one customer's last order information, while i needed each customer's last order info.